Mistake greenlet_spawn has not been called
I've written a bot in a telegram, that gets a list of chat users, after which I need to write them to a database. I have three models: users, groups and user_groups. When recording, I get the following error:
"15.06.2024 01:08:36 - aiogram.event - [ERROR] - Cause exception while process update id=333211 by bot id=605730
MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 49, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python code\develop\telegram_bot\app\middlewares\middleware.py", line 20, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 170, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 162, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python code\develop\telegram_bot\app\handlers\base_handlers.py", line 26, in start
    await crud_group.add_chat_members_to_db(
  File "F:\Python code\develop\telegram_bot\app\crud\group.py", line 51, in add_chat_members_to_db
    UserGroupAssociation.group_id == group.group_id,
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 566, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(state, dict_)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1086, in get
    value = self._fire_loader_callables(state, key, passive)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1116, in _fire_loader_callables
    return state._load_expired(state, passive)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 796, in _load_expired
    self.manager.expired_attribute_loader(self, toload, passive)
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 1653, in load_scalar_attributes
    result = load_on_ident(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 509, in load_on_ident
    return load_on_pk_identity(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 694, in load_on_pk_identity
    session.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2306, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2191, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1421, in execute
    return meth(
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 514, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1643, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1849, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1989, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2359, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1970, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 924, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 146, in execute
    self._adapt_connection._handle_exception(error)
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 298, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 123, in execute
    _cursor = self.await_(self._connection.cursor())
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 118, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

This error is triggered by the highlighted line below:
from app.models.group import Group
from app.models.user_group_association import UserGroupAssociation
from sqlalchemy import select
from app.crud.base import CRUDBase
from app.crud.user_group_association import crud_user_group_association
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from app.crud.user import crud_user
from aiogram import types
from app.models.user import User


class CRUDGroup(CRUDBase):
    async def add_chat_members_to_db(
        self, chat: types.Chat, user_data: User, session: AsyncSession
    ):

        group = await session.execute(
            select(self.model).where(self.model.group_id == chat.id)
        )
        group = group.scalars().first()
        if not group:
            group = await self.create(
                {'group_id': chat.id, 'group_name': chat.title}, session
            )

        for user_info in user_data:
            print(f'user_info >>>>>>>>>>>>>{user_info}')
            user = await crud_user.get_user_id(user_info['user_id'], session)
            if not user:
                user = await crud_user.create(
                    {
                        'user_id': user_info['user_id'],
                        'user_name': user_info['user_name'],
                        'first_name': user_info['first_name'],
                        'last_name': user_info['last_name'],
                    },
                    session,
                )


            association = await session.execute(
                select(UserGroupAssociation).where(
                    UserGroupAssociation.user_id == user.user_id,
                    UserGroupAssociation.group_id == group.group_id,  # Error is triggered here.
                )
            )
            association = association.scalars().first()
            if not association:
                await crud_user_group_association.create(
                    {
                        'user_id': user.user_id,
                        'group_id': group.group_id,
                        'is_admin': user_info['is_admin_or_creator'],
                    },
                    session,
                )


crud_group = CRUDGroup(Group)


I tried to add lazy="selectin" in relationship It didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Hard to tell what is going on without the actual models.  Maybe try lazy="raise" as seen in preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession

It might be a different relationship than you think being eager loaded by accident.
